# Convert numpy flow control syntax to regular python syntax

Tags: python, numpy, conditional-statements, pvlib

I have one more question on numpy python module syntax, which I would like to convert into regular python 2.7 syntax. Here is the numpy version:

```
if any((var.theta < 0) | (var.theta >= 90)):
    print('Input incident angles <0 or >=90 detected For input angles with absolute value greater than 90, the ' + 'modifier is set to 0. For input angles between -90 and 0, the ' + 'angle is changed to its absolute value and evaluated.')
    var.theta[(var.theta < 0) | (var.theta >= 90)]=abs((var.theta < 0) | (var.theta >= 90))
```

source code:
https://github.com/Sandia-Labs/PVLIB_Python/blob/master/pvlib/pvl_physicaliam.py#L93-95

If we pretend that numpy arrays are one dimensional, would regular python 2.7 syntax look something like this:

```
newTheta = []
for item in var.theta:
    if (item < 0) and (item >= 90):
        print('Input incident angles <0 or >=90 detected For input angles with absolute value greater than 90, the ' + 'modifier is set to 0. For input angles between -90 and 0, the ' + 'angle is changed to its absolute value and evaluated.')
        newItem = abs(item)
        newTheta.append(newItem)
```

??
Thank you for the reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In words, what the `if any((var.theta < 0) | (var.theta >= 90))` expression means: "If any of the entries in var.theta are less than zero **or** are greater than or equal to 90, do..."

What your flow of control statement says is "If an entry of var.theta is less than 0 **and** greater than or equal to 90, do...".

If you really meant **or** in the plain Python example, then yes, it would look like this. Alternatively though, you could use list comprehension:

`newTheta = [abs(item) for item in var.theta if (item < 0 or item >= 90)]`

List comprehension is more compact, which for simple operations is easier to read, and is easier for the interpreter to optimize.

Comment: Thank you for the reply MobiusKlein.
So in numpy `|` replaces `or`. What about `and`? What is the replacement syntax for `and`?

Comment: Numpy overloads the binary and operator '&' to do vectorized logical ands.  The code would be like so `cond_1 & cond_2`, and in the plain Python case, the and keyword is all you need.